# How to avoid rebind in allocator<T, N> c++17

Tags: c++, allocator

Before c++17, if you have an allocator like `Allocator<typename, size_t>` you can use the rebind struct.
But now, in C++17 the rebind struct is deprecated.
What's the solution to construct an `allocator<T,size_t>` from an `allocator<T2, size_t>`?

Comment: The standard never has any allocator like `Allocator<typename, size_t>`. If a third party allocator has a non-type template parameter, then it must have a `rebind` member, or it will not meet the allocator requirements.

Comment: it must have a rebind member also in C++17? Is it not deprecated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only `std::allocator`'s `rebind` member template is deprecated. If you are using your own class, you can still define `rebind`.

Do it through [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits), like:

```
using AllocatorForU = std::allocator_traits<AllocatorForT>::template rebind_alloc<U>;
```

The default for `rebind_alloc` for `AllocatorTemplate<T, OtherTypes...>` is `AllocatorTemplate<U, OtherTypes...>`, which works for `std::allocator`, which is why `std::allocator<T>::rebind` is deprecated. You have to define it for your class since it has a non-type template parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [std::allocator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits):

```
std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::rebind_alloc<T>
```

with potential `typename`/`template`.