# Cause of difference in performances of default pmr allocator and default std allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am trying to investigate the cause of the difference in performance between the two allocators, as shown in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource.
What I have found so far:

- In GCC, it seems that the default pmr allocator uses `monotonic_buffer_resource` but not the std allocator, according to [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7YMqz3Mab).
- I looked into the source code of the header files and `libstdc++`, but could not find how
  `monotonic_buffer_resource` was selected to be used by the default pmr allocator.
- From my reading of the source code, it seems that `std::pmr::new_delete_resource()` should be used, and that should make default std allocator and default pmr allocator the same, but obviously it is not.

```
void default_pmr_alloc() {
    std::pmr::list<int> list; // uses monotonic_buffer_resource
    for (int i{}; i != total_nodes; ++i) {
        list.push_back(i);
    }
}

void default_std_alloc() {
    std::list<int> list; // uses operator new/delete
    for (int i{}; i != total_nodes; ++i) {
        list.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: At no point did you ask a question...

Comment: @ChrisMM good point, changed the title

Comment: Are you building with optimizations turned on? If no, the reason might be the same as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72061267/3740047) post.

Comment: @Sedenion yes, `-O3`, see the compiler explorer link, https://godbolt.org/z/7YMqz3Mab

Comment: Looking at some documentation with sample output is not investigating a performance difference, and neither is reading the compiler output for a program that doesn't run anything and which you never executed. Do you have some specific benchmark code that you executed and that showed some results? What were the results? Currently I can't even tell what you're claiming without following a link.

Comment: @Useless the benchmarks are shown in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource

Comment: No, the documentation lists some "possible output". I don't know how it was compiled or executed or on what platform. You're making an assumption based on sample output instead of executing a benchmark, which is the only way to see whether your figures are actually reproducible. As a bonus, once you have a reproducible benchmark, you'll also have an actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does indeed use `new_delete_resource`. (which from `std::pmr::get_default_resource()`)

---

you can check it by

```cpp
list.get_allocator().resource()->is_equal(*std::pmr::new_delete_resource()); // true
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qGTG57MfY

---

Not sure about what the benchmark is, but type erasure comes with it's own penalty, `pmr` one would probably be slower.

Comment: Interesting, I noticed that once I comment away that return statement, `monotonic_buffer_resource` appear in the generated assembly again.

Comment: The benchmark is at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource. std::pmr is faster there

Comment: @ggg the test seems pretty reasonable afaict https://godbolt.org/z/TsGWr5vGE. default allocator is faster than pmr default (which has virtual call cost).

Comment: @ggg even comment out return, the typeid still indicate it's `new_delete_resource` https://godbolt.org/z/Paf9hPo4c

Comment: @ggg I'd guess the `monotonic_buffer_resource` name is some optimization by compiler in case it's indeed one.

Comment: @ggg and indeed it appears even though no `list` is constructed https://godbolt.org/z/cncT8Mj95

Comment: @ggg wait, you say pmr is faster, but pmr takes `0.915s` while native takes only `0.720s`? (cppreference)

Comment: thanks for checking. As to how `monotonic_buffer_resource` appears in the code for `std::pmr` containers. I will create a new question for that in the future.

Comment: just noticed my mistake, default std allocator is faster than pmr allocator

Comment: @ggg fwiw, just using `allocate` is enough to make compiler generate it https://godbolt.org/z/z7sxaoE3v (with optimize)

Comment: you have piqued my curiosity, I dug into the source code but couldn't find anything, will post a new question for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74185797/why-does-monotonic-buffer-resource-appear-in-the-assembly-when-it-doesnt-seem