# Why does `monotonic_buffer_resource` appear in the assembly when it doesn't seem to be used?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, libstdc++

This is a follow-up from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74157781/cause-of-difference-in-performances-of-default-pmr-allocator-and-default-std-all/74183319?noredirect=1#comment130979137_74183319).

I think the following code should not use `monotonic_buffer_resource`, but in the generated assembly there are references to it.

```
void default_pmr_alloc(std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int>& alloc) {
    (void)alloc.allocate(1);
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z7sxaoE3v)

I looked into the source code of the header files and libstdc++, but could not find how monotonic_buffer_resource was selected to be used by the default pmr allocator.

Comment: I'd say it's probably not *used*. just optimized (some kind of inlining) in case it's actually one.

Comment: What makes you think it was "selected to be used"?

Comment: @NicolBolas I think those are the only allocation functions in the generated assembly

Comment: Also, your function doesn't use the default PMR allocator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly tells the story. In particular, this:

```
cmp     rax, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt3pmr25monotonic_buffer_resource11do_allocateEmm
jne     .L11
```

This appears to be a test to see if the memory resource is a `monotonic_buffer_resource`. This seems to be done by checking the `do_allocate` member of the vtable. If it is *not* such a resource (ie: if `do_allocate` in the memory resource is not the monotonic one), then it jumps down to this:

```
.L11:
        mov     rdi, rbx
        mov     edx, 4
        mov     esi, 4
        pop     rbx
        jmp     rax
```

This appears to be a vtable call.

The rest of the assembly appears to be an inlined version of `monotonic_buffer_resource::do_allocate`. Which is why it conditionally calls `std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource::_M_new_buffer`.

So overall, this implementation of `polymorphic_resource::allocate` seems to have some built-in inlining of `monotonic_buffer_resource::do_allocate` if the resource is appropriate for that. That is, it won't do a vtable call if it can determine that it should call `monotonic_buffer_resource::do_allocate`.

Comment: do you know what is the name of this optimization technique? Or is it a special case optimization?

Comment: @ggg: It's some form of devirtualization. It's likely that the compiler did it for some reason (since it's directly accessing the vtable), but I can't say what caused it to happen. The easiest thing to do would be to just look at the implementation.